# Union data from cursors into one

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, cursors

I have stored procedure which executes another stored procedure several times. I need union and return data, which I have after executing second procedure.

Can I in some way union data from several cursors into one another cursor? It is possible without temporary tables or table-like datatype?

EDIT: Cursor count for union actually is n (where n is 1, 2, 3, etc, detecting by another procedure).

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_data
( data_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
BEGIN
 OPEN data_out FOR SELECT '1' NUM FROM dual;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_result
( data_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
 data1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
 data2 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
 PROC_DATA(data1);
 PROC_DATA(data2);
 -- select data1 and data2 into data_out - how?
END;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE 
 data_out SYS_REFCURSOR;
 temp_row VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
 PROC_RESULT(data_out);
  LOOP
    FETCH data_out INTO temp_row;
    EXIT WHEN data_out%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(temp_row);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE data_out;
END;
/
```

expected output:

```
---
1   
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. There's [a nice discussion](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:410118800346192093) at AskTom regarding this question, take a look maybe some workarounds provided there can help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by creating a [pipelined function](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4447489221109) which will allow you to do

```
select table(PROC_DATA(data1)) union table(PROC_DATA(data2))
```

Comment: n being constant or variable?

Comment: n - variable. This was example only for explain my question, in real db cursors count for union is detecting by another procedure.

Comment: Then you could build the select table(PROC_DATA(data1)) union table(PROC_DATA(data2)) union table(PROC_DATA(data3)) ...
query dynamically and execute it