# Oracle pl/sql cursor - "combining records" or an equivalent

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, record, oracle11gr2

I have PHP class A and class B. These exist independently, and for each I have equivalent Oracle PL/SQL definitions ie.

```
type cursorA is ref cursor return recordA;
type cursorB is ref cursor return recordB;
```

allowing the return of multiple data rows for creating multiple A or B PHP objects in a single database call. So far so good...

In certain circumstances I require a single query returning combined recordA and recordB fields in a single A+B cursor.

I can achieve this by creating a new single recordC combining all fields from recordsA and recordsB, then executing cursorC to return the logical "A+B" information, however this effectively duplicates the A and B record definitions and I would prefer to avoid this by doing something like:

```
type recordC is record (recordA plus recordB);
type cursorC is refcursor return recordC;
```

or

```
type cursorC is ref cursor return recordA plus recordB;
```

The above statements don't appear to work, but I am interested in whether  it is possible in PL/SQL to achieve some equivalent that will allow re-use/combining of the recordA and recordB definitions rather than requiring recordA and recordB field duplication in recordC.

To be clear, this is NOT a duplicate of "Union data from cursors into one". This is a single query building 1 cursor whose return columns are recordC. There would be a significant negative performance impact to "splitting" the query into 2 separate queries, and it is not the functionality I am looking for.

Comment: I believe it depends how you're mapping pl/sql fields to php class properties.

Comment: Hi @sebas - thanks, the PHP component is a bit misleading possibly as this question is all about Oracle; specifically the ability for Oracle to combine "greater than 1" record definitions into a single "super record" definition allowing for record definition re-use. (note this is is not the same as Oracle "nested records" as I do not want a parent child relationship for the fields, just a flat list of the combined fields)  ...I have to say that from what I've read it doesn't seem to be possible but I'm hoping that someone may have some insight that I'm missing.

Comment: Why not creating a single record type containing all fields types from both tables, and using that in a third cursor, defined as an explicit select with all fields you want? Do you mean to do it dynamically by "adding" the results of both cursors automatically?

Comment: @sebas - thanks for the suggestion. That is a possibility but is also one I'm not really partial to I'm afraid as it doesn't provide the encapsulation I would like at an A and B level. Just for background, my reason for the merge into C is performance and simplicity. ie. so the data can be returned in a single SQL query and single cursor from the DB, then split out into the various PHP client classes in the web environment. This approach could even possibly entail the delivery of data for  more than 2 classes (all having a 1:1 relationship) in a single call.

Comment: You could use dynamic cursor then, built on the fly with wanted objects definitions (that have to be stored somewhere). That sound like an interesting project :) But holy, kind of circumvoluted as well :P

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085014/union-data-from-cursors-into-one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. PL/SQL doesn't have support for runtime/compilation time manipulation of (record or cursor) types ([reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29)) but the data types are very static (and barebone). In some areas PL/SQL is a bit old-fashioned and verbose language.

The most PL/SQlish way to combine records is simply:

```
type recordC is record(
  a recordA
 ,b recordB
);
```

But the main power of PL/SQL is the SQL part, so if you can adjust your `select` statement(s) you might consider the following option where the data of both `A` and `B` (`foo` and `bar` respectively) is combined. This of course assumes there is a reasonable relation between them (in this example `foo.id = bar.id`):

```
create table foo (id number, str varchar2(10));
create table bar (id number, num number);

insert all
into foo(id, str) values(1, 'foo one')
into foo(id, str) values(2, 'foo two')
into bar(id, num) values(1, 100)
into bar(id, num) values(2, 200)
select 1 from dual;

select foo.id, foo.str as foo_str, bar.num as bar_num
from foo
inner join bar on bar.id = foo.id
;
```

It's your call if this a trade-off you like.

The other possible options collected from Typo's comment:

- [Union data from cursors into one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4085014/272735)
- Ask Tom: [Can Ref Cursors be concatenated?](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:410118800346192093)
- Ask Tom: [Pipelined functions](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4447489221109)

Comment: Thanks - Are you able to get a cursor working returning your recordC above as I couldn't. The code "type cursorC is refcursor return recordC;" compiles but failed on execute. If you are able to get it to run, please do paste the code sample here! thanks!